# How to write an array filter that returns all items of array that is in another array

Tags: javascript

```
assignedRoles = ['User','InCharge'];
items = ['Admin','Supervisor','User', 'InCharge'];
```

I need a filter that will return all items which are in assignedRoles.

So in the above example, the filter would return 'User' and 'InCharge'

This is what I have tried:

```
return items.filter(a=> a.any(assignedRoles);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `indexOf()`

```js
var assignedRoles = ['User', 'InCharge'];
var items = ['Admin', 'Supervisor', 'User', 'InCharge'];

var answer = items.filter(function(item) {
  return assignedRoles.indexOf(item) > -1;
});

console.log(answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `assignedRoles.indexOf() !== -1`  ( `x !== -1` is faster than `x > -1` and `x >= 0` )

```js
var assignedRoles = ['User', 'InCharge'];
    var items = ['Admin', 'Supervisor', 'User', 'InCharge'];
    
    var result = items.filter(function(item) {
      return assignedRoles.indexOf(item) !== -1;
    });
    
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you know that it is faster? And if it is, how much faster?

Comment: let me check. There is test tool in the web

Comment: I actually like `x >= 0` the best, as to me it is the most clear what it is saying.